# .timeFormat(%b %Y) not giving me the right dates

Tags: date, d3.js, formatting

I'm a beginner with d3.js. The goal for now is to take the date column from **"2018-11-01"** to **"Nov 18"**.
The dates start from "2016-11-01" to "2020-08-01" and each date in between is only the first of each month.

For example:

```
"2016-11-01", 
"2016-12-01",
"2017-01-01",
"2017-02-01",
"2017-03-01",
"2017-04-01",
"2017-05-01",
```

The code I've used is  below:

```
        var format = d3.timeFormat("%b %Y");    
        var data = d3.dsv(",", dsvPath, function (d) {
            return {
                //Year : getYear(new Date(+d.year,0,1)),
                
                date: format(new Date(d.date)),
                ['Catan=count']:+d['Catan=count'],
                ['Dominion=count']:+d['Dominion=count'],
                ['Codenames=count']:+d['Codenames=count'],
                ['Terraforming Mars=count']:+d['Terraforming Mars=count'],
                ['Gloomhaven=count']:+d['Gloomhaven=count'],
                ['Magic: The Gathering=count']:+d['Magic: The Gathering=count'],
                ['Dixit=count']:+d['Dixit=count'],
                ['Monopoly=count']:+d['Monopoly=count']
                //['Running Total'] : +d["running_total"]
            };
        }).then(function (data) {
            
            console.log(data[0]); 
            minDate = d3.min(data,function(d){console.log(d); return d.date;});
            maxDate = d3.max(data,function(d){console.log(d); return d.date;});
            console.log(minDate);
```

However, for the minimum date, I get April 2017 instead of November 2016. The max date is May 2020 instead of September 2020.

When I read in the data as is without the data formatting, the minDate and maxDate are correct. As soon as I format, however, Oct 2016, which doesn't exist in the dataset, is somehow logged twice.

Furthermore, the data in the console stops at "July 2020": there's no August and Sept 2020. I'm honestly very puzzled.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to a Date via the `Date()` constructor is notoriously tricky. Thankfully, since D3 gives us methods to go from a date to a string, [it also has the reverse](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_parse), going from **a string to a date.**

Our process will be twofold:

1. For each string in a certain format, **convert to `Date`** with `d3.timeParse()`.
2. Convert each date to your desired string format.

```
            (1.)                      (2.)
"2016-01-01"  Date<2016-01-01T00:0O>  "January 2016"
         d3.timeParse                 d3.timeFormat
```

You already have (2.) in your code, so we need (1.):

```
var toDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%M-%d");
var format = d3.timeFormat("%b %Y"); // (2.)
var data = d3.dsv(",", dsvPath, function (d) {
    return {
        date: format(toDate(d.date)),
    };
})
```